# Creating vertical dropdown that expands on click using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a vertical menu that expands on click. Each item, when clicked, should expand and display 3 links.

This is initial layout:

[image]

This after clicking **all** the items:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <div class="accordion" id="leftMenu">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#leftMenu"
                    data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo"><i class=
                    "icon-th"></i> Item 1</a>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseTwo" style=
                "height: 0px;">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li>This is one</li>
                            <li>This is two</li>
                            <li>This is Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#leftMenu"
                    data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree"><i class=
                    "icon-th-list"></i> Item 2</a>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseThree" style=
                "height: 0px;">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li>This is one</li>
                            <li>This is two</li>
                            <li>This is Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#leftMenu"
                    data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour"><i class=
                    "icon-list-alt"></i> Item 3</a>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseFour" style=
                "height: 0px;">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li>This is one</li>
                            <li>This is two</li>
                            <li>This is Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've got the expand on click functionality working fine: [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o4r4unLu/)

The problem is that the layout isn't exactly as I want it. As shown in the pictures above, I want a main container, and the menu to be displayed inside the container.

As of now, it takes up the full screen width. And the sub-menu items aren't displayed as block items.

To avoid the question getting closed as "Too broad", I'll make my question more precise:

- How to display the contents inside a main container, that takes up just a portion of the screen width, as opposed to the menu taking up the entire screen width?
- How to display the nested `<li>` as a box-like div (clickable)?

I'm totally new to Twitter bootstrap and I have a feeling I'm not using it right. Could someone please be so kind as to show me how to actually make this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use bootstrap classes "row" and "col" to control the width of the div.
2. Use a container (like the well class) around your collapsible accordion or panel.
3. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxchans/q9a5vp1a/1/) for more details. This should be enough to get you started.

```css
.well {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.subMenu {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.subMenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Item #1
                    </a>
                  </h4>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li>Item #1a</li>
                <li>Item #1b</li>
                <li>Item #1c</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      Item #2
                    </a>
                  </h4>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li>Item #2a</li>
                <li>Item #2b</li>
                <li>Item #2c</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Item #3
                    </a>
                  </h4>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li>Item #3a</li>
                <li>Item #3b</li>
                <li>Item #3c</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```